# Why is capacitance a constant (isolated charged sphere)

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I'm not getting why is the capacitance a constant, and how you can deduce it from the potential and charge.

The potential of the sphere is (in the radial magnitude)

$V(r) = \dfrac{kQ}{r} $ if $r > R$ and  $V(r) = \dfrac{kQ}{R} $ if $r \leq R$

From this the claim is that if you evaluate at $r = R$ you would get the second expression and using $Q = CV$ you get that $C = R/k$.

My question is why evaluate it at $r = R$ when you could have chosen a bigger $r$, wouldn't the constant change in that case as it is dependant of where you're looking at the potential? What am I missing? for example if $r = 2R$ I would get $C = \dfrac{2R}{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitance of an object tells you how much charge it will hold at a given applied voltage. Thus it only depends on the capacitor itself (it's length, width, or radius for example). So one would not expect it to change depending on something arbitrary, such as how far away you are from the capacitor.

The expression you're using tells you the voltage at any given position in space. But the voltage applied to the sphere only makes sense on the surface of the sphere itself, that is at $r = R$. If you had a larger sphere, say with radius $r=2R$, the capacitance *would* change. But that's only because the physical dimensions of the capacitor changed.

Comment: `The expression you're using tells you the voltage at any given position in space. But the voltage applied to the sphere only makes sense on the surface of the sphere itself` I guess this was it, I though you could talk about it for the whole space since you can get the potential for all of it.